# php.ini include_path; Not able to include PEAR packages

Tags: pear, php, include-path

I'm getting an error when trying to run a php file using browser. I guess there is some problem with include_path value in php.ini file.
Below is the error-

> Warning: require_once(System.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosweb/web116/b1166/username/temp/check_pear.php on line 2
>   Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'System.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/bin/php') in /hermes/bosweb/web116/b1166/username/temp/check_pear.php on line 2

I'm having this file "check_pear.php" in web server to check whether I'm able to include pear packages or not.

The code of check_pear.php file is-
`<?php
require_once ('System.php');
var_dump(class_exists('System', false));
?>`

I've searched a lot and also read the below article but still I'm not able to solve this issue.
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php

I don't have any command line access to my web server. Below is some information for reference-

> PHP Path: /usr/local/bin/php
>   Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib/php-5.2.17/lib
>   additional .ini files parsed: (none)

Assist me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: YOu need to update include paths, but it's hardly possible, if you're using shared hosting. Look for PEAR settings in control panel of your hosting provider. I'm afraid, this is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your php.ini, you can use

```
ini_set('include_path',ini_get('include_path').':/var/www/includes:');
```

at the top of each of your scripts (just put it in a global 'common' file) to add an additional path you want PHP to look in when searching for included files.

As for what this path should be - that depends on the file structure of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I'm still getting error. I'm using shared hosting and I'm having access to php.ini, I can manually edit php.ini. Could you tell me the procedure to find correct include_path so that I can able to run PEAR packages.@Grim,@kirilloid